# Calculate quad curve control point from on-curve point

Tags: geometry, bezier-curve

I'm trying to calculate the control point of a quad curve (I know the start and end points) so that it passes through a given point. Here is an image to help you see what I'm doing:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFvyb.png

My goal is to find the x position of the green control point. I know the y because it is always on the blue horizontal line.

So basically I know the start and end points of the curve and I know one on-curve point (red circle). I also know what the y of green control point is. I just need to know the x of the green control point so that the red circle is on the curve.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Please. Explain what do you mean by quad curve.

Comment: A quadratic bezier curve that has a start point, control point, and end point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a quadratic Bezier curve

$$
b_2(p_0,p_1,p_2,t) = (1-t)((1-t)p_0+t p_1)+t((1-t)p_1+t p_2),\ \ 0\le t\le 1
$$

we have the control point as $p_1$ now the question is. Where locate $p_1$ such that the spline passes by $p_0,q,p_2$?

we have for a suitable set $\{t^*, p_1^*\}$ that

$$
b_2(p_0,p_1^*,p_2,t^*) = q
$$

so fixing a $0\le t^* \le 1$ and giving a desired $q$ we can determine the control point $p_1^*(t^*)$ by solving

$$
 (1-t^*)((1-t^*)p_0+t^* p_1^*)+t^*((1-t^*)p_1^*+t^* p_2) = q
$$

Attached a plot showing the case

$$
q = (0.8,0.6)  \ \ \mbox{red}\\
p_0 = (0,2) \ \ \mbox{red}\\
p_1^* = (1.66667,0.416667) \ \ \mbox{green}\\
p_2 = (0,-2) \ \ \mbox{red}\\
t^* = 0.4
$$

[image]

NOTE

Be aware that $p_1^* = p_1^*(t^*)$

Comment: Awesome thanks man!